# Is there a way to get DynamoDB table definition via AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to get DynamoDB table definition (like describe-table CLI command does) via AWS console?

Answer (score 1):

Definition as in schema, then no. DynamoDB is schemaless, so you only define the partition and/or sort key.

You can do a small Scan and interpret the full schema from there, but it's not guaranteed to be correct.

If you mean definition as in the configuration like DescribeTable outputs, then all of those values are in the web console under the table summary.

Comment: Thank you. partition, sort key, attribute definitions, global attribute definitions, TTL etc - all those values are in the console, but they are scattered over multiple tabs. What I am looking for is the way to review everything at a glance, to copy and save the definition (or should I say "configuration"?) for future reference or to compare to some other table's definition. *describe-table* CLI command does that - but I don't see any kind of equivalent output in the console.

Comment: There's not. To get JSON output like that you need to do so using CLI or SDK.